# Chrome DHC - Crashes trying load previous run query?

Tags: crash, dhc

I've been using DHC for awhile now. And I've noticed that my previous run queries take a long time to load, and the latest query crashes DHC each time I try to open it.

I'm confused as to why its taking so long, its like its trying to run the query (which returns several hundred rows of JSON). I have not clicked Query, and it acts like its trying to retrieve previous data.

Its gotten to the point of the browser crashes each time i try to open DHC. And I'm not sure how to work-around this issue so I can get DHC working again.

Any ideas?

Comment: To get around this I remove it from Chrome and re-install it.
It's not a great suggestion by the only way that I've found so far.